# How to input value from user and save in variable wxDev-C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am new to wxDev-C++, I am pretty familiar with **OOP**  and **Dev C++**, now I am interested to work with GUI and I found **wxDev-C++** as my new friend.

Can any one tell me how to input from user and save it in a variable as we do in Dev?

```
string input;
cin >> input;
```

and further process with input. I want to do that in GUI programming using **wxDev-C++** or if possible, please give me link to the best book regarding it.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you use a modern C++11 compiler like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/)? You really should use C++11 ... Regarding GUI, consider [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) (BTW, all of these are available on most Linux distributions)

Comment: i Don't Know About GCC or Clang, only worked in Dev c++ with MingW.

Comment: [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) contains some [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) variant. Be sure to use a recent one. But consider using Qt. BTW, you'll learn a big lot by installing and using Linux.

Comment: can you please tell me what should i do now, migration from MingW to GCC or ------.......?

Comment: I'm biased, but I would suggest to install Linux on your laptop and use Qt.

Comment: Sir thanks for your suggestion,Linux OS would lead me to explore its features it may take several days  to understand. After that chunk of time to understand QT Related to Linux. not a good opetion for me.

Comment: The point (even with WxWidgets) is to understand what an event loop is and how graphical applications are organized around it. Yes, understanding that takes weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you've already created a window with wxDev (if not, follow the tutorials). Add a [`WxTextCtrl`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_text_ctrl.html).

Call `->GetLineText(0)` on the text control widget to the the first line of text (by default text controls allow only one line of text). You probably want to do this in response to `EVT_TEXT_ENTER`.

Comment: Thank you so Much it is near to my expectations. And it is working,cheked. Actually i am working on winsock2, i will receive some data using socket programming than i will show it over GUI.